# parse rss with php , preg_match function "edit : str_replace"

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I'm `parsing` this `rss` with `php` and i'm trying to display the youtube video.In the first `item` i'm getting an error and the video is not displayed.In the second `item` the video is displayed  normally.
**I have to remove `123.gr//` from this line** :

```
 <iframe width="780" height="470" src="'http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/embed/WDK5BTuFMRM?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I thought that a good idea to do that is to use **`explode function`**  But i didn't find the way yet.

Take a look in my code :

```
<?php
            $html = "";
            $url = "123.xml";
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
                $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
                $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
                print_r(explode('"',$description,5));
?>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
                <h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $description ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php   
            }
        ?>
```

Here's is a sample of the rss

```
<item>
  <title>This is the title</title>
  <description>
     <![CDATA[Some text
      <p>
      <div align="center">
      <iframe width="780" height="470" src="'http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/embed/WDK5BTuFMRM?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    ]]>
  </description>
</item>
<item>
  <title>This is the title</title>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Some text
        <p>
        <div align="center">
        <iframe width="780" height="470" src="'http://www.youtube.com/embed/WDK5BTuFMRM?rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      ]]>
   </description>
 </item>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally i use the str_replace and displays both videos.Here's is my code , maybe will help someone in the future

```
<?php
        $html = "";
        $url = "http://123.gr/index.php?format=feed&type=rss";
              $xml = file_get_contents($url);
          $x = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);


          foreach ( $x->channel->item as $entry ){
              $part_to_replace   = array("http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/");
              $replaced   = array("http://www.youtube.com/");
              $entry->description = str_replace( $part_to_replace, $replaced, $entry->description );
              echo $entry->description;
                  echo $entry->title;     
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to get all youtube links:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('[(?P<link>www\.youtube\.com.*?)"]', $xml, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This will give you an array in `$matches` which contains all links to youtube videos found in your rss xml.

Comment: thanks for your answer benjamin , but i need to keep the iframe element <iframe width="780" height="470" src="www\.youtube\.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>

Comment: find out how it works.late night i'll upload the code!